# iot-smart-home-cloud (gcp project) registered devices not appear in the flutter app and in Angular/web

Tags: angular, flutter, google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have this issue open on github for 10 days: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-smart-home-cloud/issues/20

I can see the devices registered in the firestore(look photo below), but they do not appear on the mobile screen or in the Angular/web application. In the latter case, the devices are correctly registered in the GCP/Cloud Iot Core Api/PubSub.

I already registered 1 device using the tutorial below, which also does not appear
http://nilhcem.com/iot/cloud-iot-core-with-the-esp32-and-arduino

How to solve?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you successfully register the device in the gcp iot-core? The error log you included in the github issue mentioned that it was not able to register the device, so I'm not sure if the issue here is that you are not registering the devices to iot-core, which will explain why you're not able to see them later on

Comment: @Tlaquetzal Yes, I'm sure: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CmIkfbL4THTDB-MhLdRNNYBNniQwP65e?usp=sharing

Comment: The image you shared showed the registries, not the devices in the registries. One of your logs show a permission error,  so, focusing on the Web App, do you see any errors in the Console tab or Network tab? If there are insufficient permissions to list the devices, that could be the error you're facing.

Comment: @Tlaquetzal tks for now.  I activated notifications on my gcp-android-app and as soon as I tried something I received a notification which is below. Were you able to develop this project? I would like to have your github so I can add it to the private github for this project. I read in the medium written by Devunwired(said below) that there is a part of the cloud functions that "listen" to the pending collection and transform it into devices-config (collection). I'm checking if this is happening here or not: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Rgsv8i9-nd8w844Fxb1kxplMPPgXsGir?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tlaquetzal Really, the issue goes through the firebase Cloud Functions. 
I do this tutorial and I create a f2f device
https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/2ba2390dddb991a12c4f992553a8059f              logs from firebase/cloud functions console:
https://gist.github.com/neuberfran/ef15a668fed3e47ed1e2e00987a15a34

Comment: @Tlaquetzal https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RKzthowskHdBfH5OJBxWasoY2dIKm1ZU?usp=sharing

Comment: In the last gist that you shared you showed that you created a device in the registry "io2019"; however, the log file showed that the device was looked for in the registry "iotcore-registry". This is because the registry name is taken from the config, which is set in step 3 of the [quickstart](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-smart-home-cloud/blob/master/firebase/README.md#quickstart), that's why you are seeing the not found error. Try creating the device in the iotcore-registry or change the firebase function configuration

Comment: @Tlaquetzal tks. Yessterday I Solved.There is still something to fix in the openssl command (as can be seen in the photo below) but my main goal is to integrate something here with google assistant/ smart home and not necessarily the cloud iot core/pub/sub

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_-psIG7X6t_Z1TnPlBqmkVpQ35b7Exz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Glad it worked. For your other two concerns (open ssl) and change the integration, try creating two new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the error message in the screenshots mentions an issue with the authentication, the real error message was the "Device Not Found".

The issue was that the code was looking for a specific registry-device that didn't exist due to a mismatch in the registry name.

For reference, the configuration of the iot settings in firebase is mentioned in the step 3 of the [quickstart](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-smart-home-cloud/tree/master/firebase#quickstart):

> Add your Cloud IoT Core project info as Firebase config environment variables:
>
> ```
> $ firebase functions:config:set \
> cloudiot.region=$REGION \
> cloudiot.registry=$REGISTRY
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The [Device Manager sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-smart-home-cloud) you are working with registers the data scanned from a device QR code to the `pending` Firestore collection until until the backend can establish that the data provided matches an existing valid device in Cloud IoT Core (see the [relevant code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-smart-home-cloud/blob/master/firebase/functions/device-cloud/register-device.js#L62)).

If you are able to successfully register a device to `pending` but it's never removed from that collection, then the issue is in that code path somewhere. The cloud function logs should provide some insight into why your code is failing there (e.g. invalid credentials, bad configuration, etc.)

You might also find [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-smart-home-cloud-service-with-google-1ee436ac5a03) helpful, which overviews the architecture of the sample code's use case.